# How to query only the specific fields in MongoDB with Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, query-optimization, mongodb-query, crud

I'm using MongoDB 3.2 and MongoDB Java Driver 3.2. In order to query document I use the following code:

```java
Document query = new Document("fetchStatus", new Document("$lte", fetchStatusParam));
ArrayList<Document> unfetchedEvents = dbC_Events.find(query).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

This query works but the problem is that in this case all fields of the document are retrieved (analog of `select *` in SQL). In order to optimize query performance, I want to specify fields I really need and fetch only them.

I found couple of examples, such as:

```java
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("Name", 1);
coll.find(query, fields);
```

but all of them are designed for outdated version of MongoDB Java Driver, e.g. 2.4, while I'm using 3.2.

How can I query only specific fields of document in MongoDB Java Driver 3.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [`.projection()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html) method that is chainable to the query result which allows you to specify fields.

Either expressed as a document, with the familiar and well documented BSON syntax:

```
    ArrayList<Document> unfecthedEvents = collection.find(
        new Document("fetchStatus", new Document("$lte", fetchStatusParam))
    ).projection(
        new Document("Name",1)
    ).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Or as a [`fields`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html#fields-org.bson.conversions.Bson...-) property builder which really just translates to exactly the same BSON:

```
    ArrayList<Document> unfecthedEvents = collection.find(
        new Document("fetchStatus", new Document("$lte", fetchStatusParam))
    ).projection(
            fields(include("Name"))
    ).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Comment: Great, `.projection(fields(include("Name")))` works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me as well:

```java
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();     

// the conditions in where query
whereQuery.put("dzeeClient", dzeeClient);
whereQuery.put("recommendationRunType", planView);
whereQuery.put("recommendedPlans.enrolled",employeeViewed);

// the fields to be returned from the query-only loginId, and remove _id
fields.put("loginId", 1); 
fields.put("_id", 0);

FindIterable<Document> cursor = collection.find(whereQuery)
                    .projection(fields).sort(new BasicDBObject("timeStamp",-1)).limit(1);
```